# Issues with Nodemailer in Node.js - Subject Showing in Message Body and Placeholder Issue

Tags: node.js, slack-api, nodemailer

I'm facing an unexpected issue while using Nodemailer in Node.js via slack, The subject, which should be in the email subject line, is appearing in the message body. Below is a snippet of the relevant code

```
app.view('your_view_callback_id', async ({ ack, body, client }) => {
    console.log('View Submission Payload:', JSON.stringify(body, null));
    const subject = body.view.state.values.uik1r.sl_input.value;
    const message = body.view.state.values["35GrF"].ml_input.value;
    await sendEmail(client, subject, message)
    await ack();
    console.log('Acknowledged view submission', body);
});



async function sendEmail(subject, message){

    console.log('Subject:', subject);
    console.log('Message:', message);

   const transporter =  nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
        }
    })

    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
          from: "SlackEmail <motty6700@gmail.com>",
          to: "techsupport@fidelitypayment.com",
          subject:`This is just a test ${subject}`,
          text: message
    })
    console.log("message sent:" + info.messageId);
    console.log("Message info:", info);
    console.log("message rejected:" + info.rejected)
}
```

the subject will be logged under the message params
console.log('Message:', message); as you can see in the logs

Message: Tech support
message sent:2ddfbd90-6f59-4cad-2263-b956ca9a4255@gmail.com  "Tech support" was suppose to be under subject,   the console.log(subject) doesn't even show up in the logs.

I am also encountering an issue with the placeholder in the subject line. I tried adding some static content, The placeholder text is not displaying correctly, resulting in unexpected content such as "This is just a test [object Object].",  but this does show up in the subject line

here you can see the full payload

```
{
  "type": "view_submission",
  "team": {
    "id": "T7W2JV1EV",
    "domain": "fidelitypaymentserv"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "UUE442C3E",
    "username": "mekstein",
    "name": "mekstein",
    "team_id": "T7W2JV1EV"
  },
  "api_app_id": "A0678L7J0A3",
  "token": "2IOpUFegFduPd4egrd7BU7Il",
  "trigger_id": "6269446301462.268086987505.739b418412dd1862ec8360bbe92ba936",
  "view": {
    "id": "V0683UZ2E1Z",
    "team_id": "T7W2JV1EV",
    "type": "modal",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "input",
        "block_id": "uik1r",
        "label": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Subject",
          "emoji": true
        },
        "optional": false,
        "dispatch_action": false,
        "element": {
          "type": "plain_text_input",
          "action_id": "sl_input",
          "placeholder": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Placeholder text for single-line input",
            "emoji": true
          },
          "dispatch_action_config": {
            "trigger_actions_on": [
              "on_enter_pressed"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "input",
        "block_id": "35GrF",
        "label": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Message",
          "emoji": true
        },
        "optional": false,
        "dispatch_action": false,
        "element": {
          "type": "plain_text_input",
          "action_id": "ml_input",
          "placeholder": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Placeholder text for multi-line input",
            "emoji": true
          },
          "multiline": true,
          "dispatch_action_config": {
            "trigger_actions_on": [
              "on_enter_pressed"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "private_metadata": "",
    "callback_id": "your_view_callback_id",
    "state": {
      "values": {
        "uik1r": {
          "sl_input": {
            "type": "plain_text_input",
            "value": "Testing"
          }
        },
        "35GrF": {
          "ml_input": {
            "type": "plain_text_input",
            "value": "P200 is working as expected"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hash": "1701380188.P487UEAT",
    "title": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Modal Title",
      "emoji": true
    },
    "clear_on_close": false,
    "notify_on_close": false,
    "close": null,
    "submit": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Submit",
      "emoji": true
    },
    "previous_view_id": null,
    "root_view_id": "V0683UZ2E1Z",
    "app_id": "A0678L7J0A3",
    "external_id": "",
    "app_installed_team_id": "T7W2JV1EV",
    "bot_id": "B067LAB1GVB"
  },
  "response_urls": [],
  "is_enterprise_install": false,
  "enterprise": null
}
```

I have been working on this for hours already, I appreciate any assistace into resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems you call the given method with three parameters:

```
await sendEmail(client, subject, message)
```

but it requires only two:

```
async function sendEmail(subject, message){
```

- remove the unused parameter
- add another parameter like `_client` to the method

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked as expected, however, why is the body message coming in like this

TW9zaGUNCltFWFRFUk5BTCBFTUFJTF0NCg=

Comment: As it seems it is base64 encoded (check here: https://www.base64decode.org/), looks like something is misconfigured.

Comment: Yes, it is encoded, I tried this attempt
const base64encodedMessage = body.view.state.values["35GrF"].ml_input.value;
    const message = Buffer.from(base64encodedMessage, 'base64').toString('utf-8')

but got back this in the body " '^�+r

Comment: Hmmm, I just checked it with `atob()` and it works well. But at the end a `=` character is missing, so i had to add it manually.
Maybe it should be fixed on the sender' side.

Comment: atob() wouldn't only work for browser?
i tried and got back some symbols

Comment: yes, tried it in the browser
for node, check this stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mrxv6v?file=index.js
so it works - at least for me, tbh i have no clue why it returns alien letters :(